# How to identify an Org from the Org Id

Tags: administration

Does anyone know if there's a way of identifying an Org based on the Org Id?

I received the "org recently accessed using SSL3.0" email that is going to admins at the moment because of the SSL switchoff, and it includes the Org ID. I work with a lot of Orgs. I'm not confident that there's any quick way to work out which Org this relates to, but if there is, it will save me logging in to a lot of Orgs to find which one it relates to.

Answer (score 10):

It's not a complete solution, more of a clue about which Org you are dealing with.

Have a look at the pod identifier. This is the forth character in the ID and comes straight after the 00D keyprefix.

With this you can determine the Pod/Server that the Org was created on (see important Caveat below). There is [a separate question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/7665/102) that lists how to do the mapping in more detail.

E.g. If the Org ID was 00D**E**00001234ooT, then the Pod identifier is E, which corresponds to NA9.

Probably the best information from this approach is if you are dealing with a Sandbox or a production Org.

## Caveat

The **BIG** problem with this approach is that it doesn't account for Orgs that are migrated from one Pod to another. This does occur and makes such an approach unpopular with a number of people. Use it as you will.

Pods also change over time, such as new ones being activated.

---

You may also want to look into the [Environment Hub](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=environment_hub_main.htm) to manage multiple Organizations that you own:

> The Environment Hub main page displays a list of all member organizations connected to the hub. For each organization, its
>   name, description, edition, **organization ID**, single sign-on status, and other details are displayed.

Or the License Management App for client orgs using a managed package.

Comment: Environment Hub is freely available, or is it an additional cost?  I'd heard about it but I didn't realise it was widely available.

Comment: @StevenHerod To be perfectly honest I haven't used the Environment Hub yet. Based on [Setting up Environment Hub](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=environment_hub_setup.htm&language=en_US) it should work for Enterprise, Performance and Unlimited editions and can be enabled by contacting support. There is no mention of a separate SKU to have it.

Answer (score 5):

I've been using this [tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/forcecom-logins/ldjbglicecgnpkpdhpbogkednmmbebec) which lets me switch between orgs quickly. Once I'm in an org, I go to Developer Console -> Execute Anonymous Apex and use

```
UserInfo.getOrganizationId()
```

This would return your org id. I've been able to swoop through around 30 odd orgs in a matter of minutes using the tool and the above approach.

Comment: I would pay very close attention to the security notice in the app description.