# go around with NO_SINGLE_MAIL_PERMISSION in managed package

Tags: managed-package, singleemailmessage, deliverability

We have **Schedulable Apex** class inside **Managed Package** which sends us **emails** (using `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`) about our package performance.

Short code example :

```java
global without sharing class SchedulablePerformanceActivityCheck implements Schedulable {
    global String emailAddress = 'vitaliy@vitalik.vitalii';
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sC) { 
        try {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setToAddresses(emailAddress);
            mail.setCcAddresses(emailAddress);
            mail.setReplyTo(emailAddress);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Vitaliy');
            mail.setSubject('Performance check'); 
            mail.setBccSender(false);
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mail.setPlainTextBody('some data');
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

In some organizations we get next error :
"`NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION, Single email is not enabled for your organization or profile`".

And based on this questions and the answer to it :

- [NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION Error from Unit Test on SingleMailMessage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8959/no-mass-mail-permission-error-from-unit-test-on-singlemailmessage)

We should change the "Access level" parameter to "All Emails", and it makes sense.
In all orgs where it fails **Access level** = "**System Email only**"

So my **question** is :
*Can we **send email** from the **Managed Package** without changing the **Access level** config ?*

Is there any way/trick to ***go around*** this ?

*Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.*

Comment: Package a Remote Site configuration that points to a REST API you create on your PBO and have your package "phone home" using a REST call instead of using an email to send these details...

Comment: @PhilW Thanks, It is a good idea. However I have already build a lot of logic which depends on that emails, I have Email Service which handles these email and logs the data. But if I don't get another solution I will go with your option !