# How do I identify whether a batch process was run from Production or testing?

Tags: apex, batch

I am setting up a result process based on batches and just wondered if there is a way to identify if the batch is run from the Production or Testing environment.

Comment: Have a look here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50/can-we-determine-if-the-salesforce-instance-is-production-org-or-a-sandbox-org

Comment: If your results are sent via email then the subject will start with "Sandbox: " when sent from a sandbox and wont have it in production.

Answer (score 2):

The answer @BarCotter posted above in the comments is the simplest way to know, which is that your Sandbox emails will be prefixed with "Sandbox: " in the Subject line out of the box. In fact, you can't even turn this off (as seen [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gufTAAQ))

I found the same question posted on StackOverflow that gives some additional options around retrieving the URL of your Salesforce org and letting you work with that. However, based on your question, working this these are probably outside the scope of what you really want to do.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507718/how-do-i-detect-the-environment-in-salesforce