# How to execute a class in Sandbox enviroment only, but have it on production as well?

Tags: apex, sandbox

I have created a couple of classes and a flow, that fill my sandbox with random data.

I want to have these classes available to all future sandboxes that I create, but I don't want to enable that class to run on my production org.
I will deploy them to my production org for future sandboxes.

- I am the only admin, and I know I can control this, but I want to know, if I can code anything that will prevent a certain class to run in production org.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50/can-we-determine-if-the-salesforce-instance-is-production-org-or-a-sandbox-org) should help you.

Long story short, method:

```
public static Boolean runningInASandbox() {
  return [SELECT Id, IsSandbox FROM Organization LIMIT 1].IsSandbox;
}
```